# How can I log in to my administrator account with cmd?

Tags: windows, authentication, cmd

I have a Windows Server 2012 and want to log in to it remotely.
I know that this possible with the Microsoft Remote Desktop program, but I want to do this with cmd, so that im able to create a script. So far I've build up a ssh connection to my server and I'm able to access the command-line tool but I'm not able to start my desired program. It's telling me that I'm logged in with the "LocalSystem". So my question is, how can I log in to my administrator account with cmd?

Edit:

Basically I want to login with my credentials  **in my own script**.
[image: Picture]

Comment: Something like this? http://emcosoftware.com/remote-console  or what about this?  http://serverfault.com/questions/429426/how-can-i-connect-to-a-windows-server-using-a-command-line-interface-cli

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but i have already a connection, its just the login process which is missing...